# Beacons integration without application on device

Tags: ibeacon, beacon

Can i know is it possible to communicate with Beacon without having any Mobile app on device?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Android and iOS devices need some kind of app installed to interact with your beacons.  Some phones have such apps pre-installed, but the options are limited.  The two such apps with the widest distribution are:

**Google Chrome App** (Android/iOS)

Google's Chrome app will interact with beacons supporting Eddystone-URL (also known as physical web), which transmit a URL that can be displayed within Chrome when the app detects it.

This works on both Android and iOS devices with Chrome installed.  For newer Android phones, this is a relatively high percentage of devices.  For iOS, it is a very small percentage, as the app is not installed by default.  This makes it of very limited use on iOS.

The other real drawback to relying on Chrome for beacon detection is the hoops users have to jump through to opt-in, and the way the beacon notifications are buried.  Until users opt-in, they will see no notifications on beacon detections.  Once they do, they will see a very generic notification "Physical web beacons are nearby", and only once the user taps on that are the specifics about the web page associated with the beacon transmitted URL displayed.

**Passbook** (iOS)

Apple's passbook app will bring up a passbook entry (usually used for tickets, coupons, etc.) associated with a set of iBeacon identifiers if the user comes within range of the beacon.  In order to use this, however, the user must first download the passbook entry to his or her iPhone.  Only once this is downloaded and opened will the app respond to associated beacons.

**EDIT April 2020**: For a time prior to December 2018 Google supported app-less notifications based on beacon detection using their Google Nearby product.  This was discontinued in December 2018 due to predictable abuse and spam that it generated.  While you may find some outdated documentation online about this ability, understand that this feature no longer works.  As of this writing, my understanding is that this answer is still correct.

Comment: Good to know, I have also researched for the same. Physical Web URL introduced by Google with chrome. But seems it might have dependency on mobile device bluetooth should be on for iOS and same for android with location enabled. And we cannot over come on this dependency.

Comment: Well, bluetooth beacons will never ever work on phones that really have their bluetooth turned off.   How could they?  You might be able to use a different technology to drive beacons like audio or WiFi, but you will run into similar permission and app installation issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout Eddystones from Google. They can push you URLs even without app.

If you want to interact with beacons and do custom stuff (notifications, http requests, etc) you will need an app.

Comment: Good to know,  I have also researched for the same. Physical Web URL introduced by Google with chrome. But seems it might have dependency on  mobile device bluetooth should be on for iOS and same for android with location enabled. And we cannot over come on this dependency.