# Is it possible to broadcast a message to Android users from a beacon without an app

Tags: android, beacon, eddystone, eddystone-url

There is a technology being promoted that claims to be able to broadcast a push notification from a beacon to any Android user with bluetooth enabled within range of the beacon, with minimal or no requirements for the user to download an app for the purpose, or do anything beyond what many/most Android users have already done:

https://asirvia.com/

https://www.royaltie.com/

Is it possible to do this?  What is the process / code to make this possible?

From what I've been able to read, this appears to be impossible, or at best extremely limited, eg:
[Beacons integration without application on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655090/beacons-integration-without-application-on-device/39656346#39656346)

Thanks

Comment: You can find an explanation of the mechanism at https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/EddystoneAndThePhysicalWeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview):

> There are two basic types of experiences that you can provide using Nearby Notifications:
>
> - Link to an HTTPS URL to provide a notification to the user, and open the URL in the browser when the user taps the notification.
> - Trigger an app intent to launch an app that is already installed and perform a specific action. If the app isn't installed, the user is taken to the Play Store where the app can be installed; the user can then continue to the feature specified by the developer.
>
> Neither experience requires that an app is installed on the user's device

So basically the first option puts a message in the notification area by publishing a message [of the format](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/attachment_data_format):

```
{
    "title": "Find out why this message has appeared on your device!",
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/q/45205406/1270789"
}
```

Comment: Android Nearby Notifications are dead. Is there any alternative? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/discontinuing-support-for-android.html